# How do i review this low-quality-post?

Tags: support, review

The answer in this [question](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/9638/ordination-procedure-in-theravada-buddhism-what-if-parents-are-not-alive-anymo) has been flagged as *low-quality* and i'm now trying to review it.

I find it very difficult to review it. I have put the following comment to the answer:

> *"Thanks for the story i didnt know this one and it was nice to get some background info to the rule. As Chris said it does however not answer the question. Also one-line-answers and link-only-answers cannot be considered answers. Here is a guide for new user on Buddhism SE which you might find useful: meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/…"*

Still the review says that i must pick one of the 4 options; *Looks OK, Edit, Deletion, Skip* in order to clear the queue. What do i choose? I was thinking of *Looks OK* but it does not look OK in its current framework.

This is currently how is looks in the low-quality-review after posting a comment. You might have to zoom in to see the pic.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think normally once you have added a comment it gives you an option of "I'm done". You may have to initially select Edit though. The comment you left was very helpful to the person answering as you gave both specifics on how the answer could be improved and linked the Welcome info too

Perhaps the "I'm done" option only appears after the comment has been added?

Or possibly that only appears on other types of reviews other than low-quality post. It's been a while since I've had a low-quality to review
; so I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Robin. I thought too that the "I'm done" option would appear but it does not exist in "low-quality-reviews". There are only the 4 options listed above. In the review it says this: "You can also leave a comment on the answer, but you will still need to choose one of the above actions to clear the post from the review queue".

Comment: I guess i will pick the "Looks OK" option since i cannot edit the answer, i will not recommend deletion and i will not skip it.

Comment: Strange. So it doesn't count leaving a comment as an "edit"?

Comment: Maybe someone else will know. I'm glad you asked so we'll all know for next time. :)

Comment: Robin i have attached a picture to my question so you can see how it looks. Its a bit odd since the other reviews have the "I'm done" option. Anyway thank you for replying i was at a loss with this one. I did now choose the "Looks OK" option to clear the queue.